# Parsing properties from certain nodes in XML using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml

Suppose, I have an XML with descriptions of files and directories (where XML nodes of files that belong to some directory are nested into that directory's corresponding XML node):

```
<list>
<signature>
hash...
</signature>
  <file id="44">
   <data>
    <length>1759</length>
    <offset>36491175</offset>
    <size>1018</size>
    <encoding style="application/x-gzip"/>
    <extracted-checksum style="sha1">91e4e9a81d6b8abb07fd6009afe72178997c512b</extracted-checksum>
    <archived-checksum style="sha1">f141cb115e21de3320c1afccd2dc115b78f83661</archived-checksum>
   </data>
   <type>file</type>
   <name>dist.dat</name>
  </file>
  <file id="6">
   <ctime>1970-01-01T00:00:00Z</ctime>
   <mtime>1970-01-01T00:00:00Z</mtime>
   <atime>1970-01-01T00:00:00Z</atime>
   <group>wheel</group>
   <gid>0</gid>
   <user>root</user>
   <uid>0</uid>
   <mode>0700</mode>
   <deviceno>0</deviceno>
   <inode>0</inode>
   <type>directory</type>
   <name>src</name>
   <file id="7">
    <ctime>1970-01-01T00:00:00Z</ctime>
    <mtime>1970-01-01T00:00:00Z</mtime>
    <atime>1970-01-01T00:00:00Z</atime>
    <group>wheel</group>
    <gid>0</gid>
    <user>root</user>
    <uid>0</uid>
    <mode>0700</mode>
    <deviceno>0</deviceno>
    <inode>0</inode>
    <type>directory</type>
    <name>Dede</name>          // ! Notice no closing </file> tag yet because next file is inside this directory
    <file id="8">
     <data>
      <length>514</length>
      <offset>36357051</offset>
      <size>859</size>
      <encoding style="application/x-gzip"/>
      <extracted-checksum style="sha1">b13b86984f1ceeb698e879ad4a0c4174804529c3</extracted-checksum>
      <archived-checksum style="sha1">414b16e24dbbbbf864d68bcde726d52d69a4dc04</archived-checksum>
     </data>
     <type>file</type>
     <name>Hello.txt</name>
    </file>
    <file id="9">
     <data>
      <length>776</length>
      <offset>36357665</offset>
      <size>1630</size>
      <encoding style="application/x-gzip"/>
      <extracted-checksum style="sha1">318eec584b12f2333133d8d07bf6b2d883fa7070</extracted-checksum>
      <archived-checksum style="sha1">c1d196e28e7a8ec0444f7d16f205bd67667f5eec</archived-checksum>
     </data>
     <type>file</type>
     <name>Local_st.txt</name>
    </file>
   </file>                         // ! Closing </file> tag for the 'Dede' directory
   ... More File Nodes
   </list>
```

What would be the best way to collect the offsets (or any desired properties for that matter) from all file nodes that have `<type>file</type>` and disregard "file" nodes that have `<type>directory</type>`?

Is there a native way or a library to do it? Or, if I manage to convert this XML into a JASON first, how would I do it then? This has to work completely browser-side.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using XPath e.g. `//file[type = 'file']/data/offset` with either browser APIs like the DOM Level 3 XPath API `evaluate` method on document nodes

```js
const xml = `<list>
<signature>
hash...
</signature>
  <file id="44">
   <data>
    <length>1759</length>
    <offset>36491175</offset>
    <size>1018</size>
    <encoding style="application/x-gzip"/>
    <extracted-checksum style="sha1">91e4e9a81d6b8abb07fd6009afe72178997c512b</extracted-checksum>
    <archived-checksum style="sha1">f141cb115e21de3320c1afccd2dc115b78f83661</archived-checksum>
   </data>
   <type>file</type>
   <name>dist.dat</name>
  </file>
  <file id="6">
   <ctime>1970-01-01T00:00:00Z</ctime>
   <mtime>1970-01-01T00:00:00Z</mtime>
   <atime>1970-01-01T00:00:00Z</atime>
   <group>wheel</group>
   <gid>0</gid>
   <user>root</user>
   <uid>0</uid>
   <mode>0700</mode>
   <deviceno>0</deviceno>
   <inode>0</inode>
   <type>directory</type>
   <name>src</name>
   <file id="7">
    <ctime>1970-01-01T00:00:00Z</ctime>
    <mtime>1970-01-01T00:00:00Z</mtime>
    <atime>1970-01-01T00:00:00Z</atime>
    <group>wheel</group>
    <gid>0</gid>
    <user>root</user>
    <uid>0</uid>
    <mode>0700</mode>
    <deviceno>0</deviceno>
    <inode>0</inode>
    <type>directory</type>
    <name>Dede</name>          
    <file id="8">
     <data>
      <length>514</length>
      <offset>36357051</offset>
      <size>859</size>
      <encoding style="application/x-gzip"/>
      <extracted-checksum style="sha1">b13b86984f1ceeb698e879ad4a0c4174804529c3</extracted-checksum>
      <archived-checksum style="sha1">414b16e24dbbbbf864d68bcde726d52d69a4dc04</archived-checksum>
     </data>
     <type>file</type>
     <name>Hello.txt</name>
    </file>
    <file id="9">
     <data>
      <length>776</length>
      <offset>36357665</offset>
      <size>1630</size>
      <encoding style="application/x-gzip"/>
      <extracted-checksum style="sha1">318eec584b12f2333133d8d07bf6b2d883fa7070</extracted-checksum>
      <archived-checksum style="sha1">c1d196e28e7a8ec0444f7d16f205bd67667f5eec</archived-checksum>
     </data>
     <type>file</type>
     <name>Local_st.txt</name>
    </file>
   </file>                         
   ... More File Nodes
  </file>
</list>`;
   
const domParser = new DOMParser();

const xmlDoc = domParser.parseFromString(xml, 'application/xml');

const result = xmlDoc.evaluate('//file[type = "file"]/data/offset', xmlDoc, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);

console.log(result.snapshotLength);

const offsets = [];
for (let i = 0; i < result.snapshotLength; i++) {
  offsets.push(result.snapshotItem(i).textContent);
}

console.log(offsets);

//alternative

const offsetNumbers = [];
for (let i = 0; i < result.snapshotLength; i++) {
  offsetNumbers.push(xmlDoc.evaluate('number()', result.snapshotItem(i), null, XPathResult.NUMBER_TYPE, null).numberValue);
}

console.log(offsetNumbers);
```

or using Saxon-JS 2 as a library you can use `//file[type = 'file']/data/offset/number()`:

```js
const xml = `<list>
<signature>
hash...
</signature>
  <file id="44">
   <data>
    <length>1759</length>
    <offset>36491175</offset>
    <size>1018</size>
    <encoding style="application/x-gzip"/>
    <extracted-checksum style="sha1">91e4e9a81d6b8abb07fd6009afe72178997c512b</extracted-checksum>
    <archived-checksum style="sha1">f141cb115e21de3320c1afccd2dc115b78f83661</archived-checksum>
   </data>
   <type>file</type>
   <name>dist.dat</name>
  </file>
  <file id="6">
   <ctime>1970-01-01T00:00:00Z</ctime>
   <mtime>1970-01-01T00:00:00Z</mtime>
   <atime>1970-01-01T00:00:00Z</atime>
   <group>wheel</group>
   <gid>0</gid>
   <user>root</user>
   <uid>0</uid>
   <mode>0700</mode>
   <deviceno>0</deviceno>
   <inode>0</inode>
   <type>directory</type>
   <name>src</name>
   <file id="7">
    <ctime>1970-01-01T00:00:00Z</ctime>
    <mtime>1970-01-01T00:00:00Z</mtime>
    <atime>1970-01-01T00:00:00Z</atime>
    <group>wheel</group>
    <gid>0</gid>
    <user>root</user>
    <uid>0</uid>
    <mode>0700</mode>
    <deviceno>0</deviceno>
    <inode>0</inode>
    <type>directory</type>
    <name>Dede</name>          
    <file id="8">
     <data>
      <length>514</length>
      <offset>36357051</offset>
      <size>859</size>
      <encoding style="application/x-gzip"/>
      <extracted-checksum style="sha1">b13b86984f1ceeb698e879ad4a0c4174804529c3</extracted-checksum>
      <archived-checksum style="sha1">414b16e24dbbbbf864d68bcde726d52d69a4dc04</archived-checksum>
     </data>
     <type>file</type>
     <name>Hello.txt</name>
    </file>
    <file id="9">
     <data>
      <length>776</length>
      <offset>36357665</offset>
      <size>1630</size>
      <encoding style="application/x-gzip"/>
      <extracted-checksum style="sha1">318eec584b12f2333133d8d07bf6b2d883fa7070</extracted-checksum>
      <archived-checksum style="sha1">c1d196e28e7a8ec0444f7d16f205bd67667f5eec</archived-checksum>
     </data>
     <type>file</type>
     <name>Local_st.txt</name>
    </file>
   </file>                         
   ... More File Nodes
  </file>
</list>`;
   
const offsets = SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate(`parse-xml($xml)//file[type = 'file']/data/offset/number()`, [], { params : { xml : xml }});

console.log(offsets);
```

```html
<script src="https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/documentation/SaxonJS/SaxonJS2.rt.js"></script>
```

Comment: How do I access individual offset values? I read the docs for `XPathResult` which you are using, and it's supposed to have `XPathResult.stringValue` property, but it's giving me an error when I am trying to call `console.log(result.stringValue);`

Comment: In XPath 1 you can select all the `offset` elements, then you need to use the DOM APIs to read e.g. the `textContent` of each element node or, if you want to stick with XPath, to read out `number()` with an `evaluate` for each `offset` element as the context node. XPath 1 has no way to give you a list of numbers or strings, XPath 2 or 3 is much more powerful and expressive and gives you all values  as a sequence or array of numbers or strings.

Comment: "XPath 2 or 3 is much more powerful and expressive and gives you all values as a sequence or array of numbers or strings." How would I do that with XPath 2 or 3? Is there any reason I would have to stick with Xpath 1?

Comment: I.e., How do I get an array of offsets? Thank you!

Comment: The original answer already had the code for XPath 3 using Saxon-JS 2 to get an array of numeric offset values, the edit I did to the XPath 1 version now has the JavaScript code to convert the XPathResult into an array of primitive values.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am super new to JS, this really helps!

Comment: I watched a tutorial on Xpath, and for relative paths the author said to use `//*/file` but you have just `//file` without asterisk. I tried both, and the results seem to be identical. Why? (should I ask it in a separate question?)

Comment: @InfiniteLoop, I don't consider a path starting with `/` or even `//` a relative path. As for the difference, `//` translates into `/descendant-or-self::node()` so your `//*/file` is `/descendant-or-self::node()/*/file` while my suggestion of `//file` is `descendant-or-self::node()/file`. That way the difference is that `//*/file` selects `file` elements being the child of at least one element while `//file` selects child elements at any level (i.e. also if the root element were a `file` element.). Any further kind of explanations would getter be given as an answer to a separate question.

Comment: Would be able to kindly help with this related question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68775253/parsing-properties-from-certain-nodes-in-xml-using-javascript-when-the-name-and