# Parsing properties from certain nodes in XML using Javascript when the name and the value are in separate XML nodes?

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath

I want to be able to parse some values in browser-side (no Node etc.) Javascript from an XML of the following format:

```
<list>
<dict>
    <key>BuildMachineOSBuild</key>
    <string>16B2555</string>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>App AutoUpdate</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>App AutoUpdate</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>AppIcon</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.app.autoupdate2</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>App AutoUpdate</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>3.8.1</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>MSau</string>
    <key>CFBundleSupportedPlatforms</key>
    <array>
        <string>MacOSX</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>3.8.16112200</string>
    <key>DTCompiler</key>
    <string>com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0</string>
    <key>DTPlatformBuild</key>
    <string>8B62</string>
    <key>DTPlatformVersion</key>
    <string>GM</string>
    <key>DTSDKBuild</key>
    <string>16B2649</string>
    <key>DTSDKName</key>
    <string>macosx10.12</string>
    <key>DTXcode</key>
    <string>0810</string>
    <key>DTXcodeBuild</key>
    <string>8B62</string>
    <key>LSHasLocalizedDisplayName</key>
    <true/>
    <key>LSMinimumSystemVersion</key>
    <string>10.10</string>
    <key>LSRequiresNativeExecution</key>
    <true/>
    <key>MbuLoggingFullLegacyUpload</key>
    <true/>
    <key>AppBuildNumber</key>
    <string>161122</string>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>NSMainNibFile</key>
    <string>SAUMainWindow</string>
    <key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>SAUApplication</string>
</dict>
</list>
```

Specifically, I want to be able to parse the values of `CFBundleIdentifier` and `CFBundleShortVersionString`. Suppose, I want to store them in an object `metadata = {id, version}`.

I learned from [Parsing properties from certain nodes in XML using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68594088/parsing-properties-from-certain-nodes-in-xml-using-javascript) how to parse data from XML nodes. The problem now is that unlike the abovementioned question, this format of XML doesn't store the values between the tags like so `<CFBundleIdentifier>com.app.autoupdate2</CFBundleIdentifier>`, but, instead, the name of the property I want to parse is between `<key>` tags and the property value follows after that--between the `<string>` tags.

If it can be done using XPATH, how would I form the query in this situation?

Comment: Use the following-sibling axis e.g. `//key[. = 'CFBundleIdentifier']/following-sibling::*[1]` gives the element node following that particular `key` element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something along these lines:

```
#this assumes your xml string is assigned to xmldoc

let domElement = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xmldoc,'text/xml');
identifiers = ["CFBundleIdentifier","CFBundleShortVersionString"]
for (let id of identifiers){
  exp = `//key[text()="${id}"]/following-sibling::string[1]/text()`;
  let target = domElement.evaluate(exp, domElement, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
  console.log(target.snapshotItem(0).nodeValue);    
}
```

Output:

```
"com.app.autoupdate2"
"3.8.1"
```

You can then assign these to whatever variables you want.

Answer (score 2):

Using JavaScript and the browser's XPath 1.0 `evaluate` method:

```js
const xml = `<list>
<dict>
    <key>BuildMachineOSBuild</key>
    <string>16B2555</string>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>App AutoUpdate</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>App AutoUpdate</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>AppIcon</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.app.autoupdate2</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>App AutoUpdate</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>3.8.1</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>MSau</string>
    <key>CFBundleSupportedPlatforms</key>
    <array>
        <string>MacOSX</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>3.8.16112200</string>
    <key>DTCompiler</key>
    <string>com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0</string>
    <key>DTPlatformBuild</key>
    <string>8B62</string>
    <key>DTPlatformVersion</key>
    <string>GM</string>
    <key>DTSDKBuild</key>
    <string>16B2649</string>
    <key>DTSDKName</key>
    <string>macosx10.12</string>
    <key>DTXcode</key>
    <string>0810</string>
    <key>DTXcodeBuild</key>
    <string>8B62</string>
    <key>LSHasLocalizedDisplayName</key>
    <true/>
    <key>LSMinimumSystemVersion</key>
    <string>10.10</string>
    <key>LSRequiresNativeExecution</key>
    <true/>
    <key>MbuLoggingFullLegacyUpload</key>
    <true/>
    <key>AppBuildNumber</key>
    <string>161122</string>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>NSMainNibFile</key>
    <string>SAUMainWindow</string>
    <key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>SAUApplication</string>
</dict>
</list>`;

const xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xml, 'application/xml');

console.log(["CFBundleIdentifier","CFBundleShortVersionString"].map(key => { return { [key] : xmlDoc.evaluate(`string(//key[. = '${key}']/following-sibling::*[1])`, xmlDoc, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null).stringValue };}));
```

Using JavaScript and Saxon-JS 2 to exploit XPath 3.1:

```js
const xml = `<list>
<dict>
    <key>BuildMachineOSBuild</key>
    <string>16B2555</string>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>App AutoUpdate</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>App AutoUpdate</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>AppIcon</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.app.autoupdate2</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>App AutoUpdate</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>3.8.1</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>MSau</string>
    <key>CFBundleSupportedPlatforms</key>
    <array>
        <string>MacOSX</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>3.8.16112200</string>
    <key>DTCompiler</key>
    <string>com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0</string>
    <key>DTPlatformBuild</key>
    <string>8B62</string>
    <key>DTPlatformVersion</key>
    <string>GM</string>
    <key>DTSDKBuild</key>
    <string>16B2649</string>
    <key>DTSDKName</key>
    <string>macosx10.12</string>
    <key>DTXcode</key>
    <string>0810</string>
    <key>DTXcodeBuild</key>
    <string>8B62</string>
    <key>LSHasLocalizedDisplayName</key>
    <true/>
    <key>LSMinimumSystemVersion</key>
    <string>10.10</string>
    <key>LSRequiresNativeExecution</key>
    <true/>
    <key>MbuLoggingFullLegacyUpload</key>
    <true/>
    <key>AppBuildNumber</key>
    <string>161122</string>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>NSMainNibFile</key>
    <string>SAUMainWindow</string>
    <key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>SAUApplication</string>
</dict>
</list>`;


console.log(["CFBundleIdentifier","CFBundleShortVersionString"].map(key => SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate(`parse-xml($xml)//key[. = $key] ! map { $key : following-sibling::*[1]/string() }`, [], { params : { xml : xml, key : key } })));
```

```html
<script src="https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/documentation/SaxonJS/SaxonJS2.rt.js"></script>
```